# Column Wise [R] Matrix Multiplication

Tags: r, matrix

NOTE: I am not referring to matrix multiplication as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22278885/4089351) - not even with the twist of the transposed discussed on the other post.

---

I have these two matrices...

Matrix **`A`**:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1), ncol=4)
       [,1]    [,2]     [,3]     [,4]  
[1,]    1       -1        1        -1       
[2,]    1        1       -1        -1     
[3,]    1        1        1         1
```

...and matrix **`B`**:

```
B <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1), ncol=3)
       [,1]    [,2]     [,3] 
[1,]    1        2        2 
[2,]    2        1        3 
[3,]    3        3        1
```

I want to get with [R] code:

```
       [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,]    1*1     1*2     1*2 
[2,]    1*2     1*1     1*3
[3,]    1*3     1*3     1*1 

       [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,]   -1*1    -1*2    -1*2 
[2,]    1*2     1*1     1*3
[3,]    1*3     1*3     1*1 

       [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,]    1*1     1*2     1*2 
[2,]   -1*2    -1*1    -1*3
[3,]    1*3     1*3     1*1 

       [,1]    [,2]    [,3] 
[1,]   -1*1    -1*2    -1*2 
[2,]   -1*2    -1*1    -1*3
[3,]    1*3     1*3     1*1
```

It's not linear algebraic multiplication because there is no sum at the end of the multiplications. It's not a Kronecker product. I have tried with `apply(A, 2, function(x) A * B` but it doesn't work, because although I can specify that I want the columns of `A` one at a time, I don't know how to do the same for the columns of `B`.

I am not set on any particular type of object (list, matrix, array) as the output.

*The question is: How can I multiply element-wise and column-wise these two matrices to end up with either another matrix or a "list" object or array?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
> lapply(as.data.frame(A), `*`, B)
$V1
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    3    3    1

$V2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1   -2   -2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    3    3    1

$V3
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2
[2,]   -2   -1   -3
[3,]    3    3    1

$V4
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   -1   -2   -2
[2,]   -2   -1   -3
[3,]    3    3    1
```

---

Regarding your follow up question in the comments below, if your end aim is for the column sums of each of these sub-matrices, you can achieve this with:

```
> lapply(as.data.frame(A), function(x) colSums(x * B))
$V1
[1] 6 6 6

$V2
[1] 4 2 2

$V3
[1] 2 4 0

$V4
[1]  0  0 -4
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you. Any chance I can bother you now for a command in R to add the separately all the columns of this list (?) or object that you displayed on your answer?

Comment: @AntoniParellada, What do you mean by "add separately"? What's the final result you are after?

Comment: `6 6 6 // 4 2 2 // 2 4 0 // 0 0 -4`

Comment: @AntoniParellada, I've updated my answer. With MrFlick's approach, you could do `apply(array(apply(A, 2, \`*\`, B), c(3,3,4)), 3, colSums)`.

Comment: Thank you. What's in the `c(3,3,4)` vector and the `,3,` part of the command? Also what operand is `*` with "`" "`" marks: `(A, 2, `*`, B)`?

Comment: @AntoniParellada, when you do `apply(A, 2, \`*\`, B)` you get a 9x4 matrix. The `array(..., c(3, 3, 4))` says to convert that 9x4 matrix into an array of 4 third-dimension elements each containing a 3x3 matrix. The `*` operand with backticks is just multiplication, but it needs to be quoted when used in this manner. Otherwise, you use an anonymous function, like MrFlick did in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you want an array or a list at the end. If an array, you can use `apply` with some reshaping

```
array(apply(A, 2, function(x) x*B), c(3,3,4))
# OR array(apply(A, 2, `*`, B), c(3,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1, -1,1,1, 1,-1,1, -1,-1,1), 3)
B <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 2,1,3, 2,3,1), 3)

C <- array(NA, c(3,3,4))
for(i in 1:4) C[,,i] <- B*A[,i]
```